# Does the thick subcategory generated by a torsion-free module contain a free module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, exact-sequence, group-extensions

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. An $R$-module $M$ is **torsion-free**, if for every regular (=non-zero-divisor) element $r\in R$ and every $m\in M$ it holds that $rm \neq 0$. We say a full subcategory $\mathcal{T}\subseteq\mathsf{Mod}_R$ is **thick**, if for every short exact sequence
$$0 \rightarrow M' \rightarrow M \rightarrow M'' \rightarrow 0$$
it holds that $M \in \mathcal{T} \iff M',M'' \in \mathcal{T}$, i.e. if it is closed under subobjects, quotients and extensions.

It is easy to see that the full subcategory $\mathsf{Tor}_R \subseteq \mathsf{Mod}_R$ of torsion modules is thick. If we restrict to finitely generated modules over a principal ideal domain, by the structure theorem this is the maximal thick subcategory of $\mathsf{Mod}_R^\text{fg}$, since any torsion-free module is free. This is to say, as soon as a thick subcategory $\mathcal{T}$ contains a torsion-free module, it holds that $\mathcal{T} = \mathsf{Mod}_R^\text{fg}$.

> How does this generalize to arbitrary (commutative) rings?

I am aware that over a general ring, torsion-free and free are distinct notions. If in general every torsion-free module $M$ would contain a free submodule $F$, then we would be done by means of the short exact sequence
$$0 \rightarrow F \rightarrow M \rightarrow M/F \rightarrow 0.$$
But unfortunately this is **not** true in general. A counterexample is given by the torsion-free $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$-module $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Note however, that this is **not** a counterexample to the maximality statement. Indeed the short exact sequence of $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$-modules
$$0 \rightarrow 2\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 0$$
shows that $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ is an extension of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ by itself, hence the thick subcategory generated by $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is all of $\mathsf{Mod}_{\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}}^\text{fg}$...

So what I want to ask is:

> Does the thick subcategory generated by a torsion-free module always contain a free module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can turn your example over $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ into an actual counterexample by making it more "infinite" so that you can't build a free module out of finitely many extensions of your module.  For instance, let $R=k\oplus V$ where $k$ is a field, $V$ is an infinite-dimensional $k$-vector space, and you make $R$ a ring by saying $xy=0$ for all $x,y\in V$.  Then the $R$-module $k=R/V$ is torsion-free, but clearly the thick subcategory it generates contains no nontrivial free module since it only contains modules that are finite-dimensional over $k$.

Or, if you want a Noetherian example, you could take $R=k[x,y]/(xy)$ and $M=R/(y)$.  Then every module in the thick subcategory generated by $M$ is annihilated by some power of $y$, and thus cannot be a nontrivial free module.

Comment: Thank you! So is there any hope to classify the thick subcategories of $\mathsf{Mod}_R^\text{fg}$ for a general ring?

Comment: The maximality does hold for modules over a domain, right? Since then, if we are given a torsion-free module $M$ and a nonzero element $m\in M$, the canonical surjective map $R \rightarrow \langle m\rangle$ has trivial kernel and thus is an isomorphism.

Comment: Right, it is trivially true over a domain.  When $R$ is Noetherian, thick subcategories of $\mathsf{Mod}_R^\text{fg}$ are in bijection with specialization-closed subsets of $\operatorname{Spec} R$: given a subset $S\subseteq\operatorname{Spec} R$, there is a thick subcategory of modules whose support is contained in $S$, and every thick subcategory is of this form.

Comment: This is very nice to know! Do you, by any chance, have a reference?

Comment: I don't know a reference for that exact statement.  An analogous statement in the derived category is in https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/004093839290047L.

Comment: To sketch the proof, the key idea is to show that a f.g. module $M$ generates the same thick subcategory as the modules $R/P$ where $P$ ranges over the minimal primes containing $\operatorname{Ann}(M)$.  In one direction, show by Noetherian induction that every submodule of $M$ is in the thick subcategory generated by modules of the form $R/P$.  In the other direction each such $P$ is an associated prime of $M$ so $M$ has a submodule isomorphic to $R/P$.  All of this is basically just the standard theory of associated primes.

Comment: Thank you very much! I only knew about the derived and stable results, but could not really find anything about the case of plain modules. I vaguely recall reading about associated primes in this context, but I couldn't find it anymore. I will use this as a nice exercise to think about...